# Installing ImageWriter for Windows

Tags: sd-card, software-installation

How do I install ImageWriter for Windows on my laptop, in order to be able to "flash" the operating system onto my SD card? I get so far, but then the system does not give me the option of the SD drive to write to.

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked their '[answers](https://answers.launchpad.net/win32-image-writer/+question/220680)' section? - your question is pretty much answered there.